Incorrect error response when using @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes annotations. Getting incorrect amount of type ids in error response
I have a Rest Controller with a single post endpoint looking like this and I want to be able to receive two different requests with different fields:
    public ResponseEntity<Void> receiveIncomingRequest(@RequestBody @Valid MainIncomingRequest mainIncomingRequest) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

The MainIncomingRequest class looks like this and EEventType is an Enum with two possible values ("firstItem" or "secondItem"):
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, visible = true, property = "eventType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FirstItem.class, name = "firstItem"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SecondItem.class, name = "secondItem")
})
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MainIncomingRequest {

    private String theId;

    private EEventType eventType;
}

And the FirstItem and SecondItem classes look similar to this:
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class FirstItem extends MainIncomingRequest {

    private String firstItemField;
}

After I make request and provide incorrect eventType enum value I get a response like this:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-07-31T20:26:15",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Could not resolve type id 'firstItemaaaa' as a subtype of `com.example.jsonsubtypesproject.dto.MainIncomingRequest`: known type ids = [MainIncomingRequest, firstItem, secondItem]",
    "path": "/main/incoming"
}

It states there are 3 known type ids. How do I make it show only two ("firstItem" and "secondItem") instead of also including the "MainIncomingRequest" ?
